# Как в java инстанцировать класс, описывающий IPv4 адрес?

Tags: java, java-8, ip-address

Необходим метод, генерирующий случайный IPv4 адрес из заданного диапазона. Не получается задать сам диапазон. Моё гугление привело меня к тому, что для хранения адреса можно использовать класс [`Inet4Address`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html), но:

- Судя по документации, экземпляры этого класса инстанцируются с помощью метода [`getByName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName-java.lang.String-), который может бросить исключение [`UnknownHostException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/UnknownHostException.html);
- Т.е., проблема в том, что этот метод является швейцарским ножом, который может превратить классическую строку вида `192.168.0.1` в необходимый объект, либо выполнить резолюцию DNS-имени, если передали `domain.com`. И в случае с резолюцией, как я понимаю, и может возникнуть исключение выше;
- Я хочу задать диапазоны адресов в классическом виде, без необходимости выполнения DNS-резолюций. Т.е. я точно знаю, что исключения `UnknownHostException` возникнуть не может, но я обязательно должен его обработать.

При таком варианте мой код получился такой:

```java
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Pair;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class IPRanges {
    static final ArrayList<Pair<InetAddress, InetAddress>> IPv4GlobalRanges = new ArrayList<Pair<InetAddress, InetAddress>>() {{
        try {
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("1.0.0.0"), InetAddress.getByName("9.255.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("11.0.0.0"), InetAddress.getByName("100.63.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("100.128.0.0"), InetAddress.getByName("126.255.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("128.0.0.0"), InetAddress.getByName("169.253.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("169.255.0.0"), InetAddress.getByName("172.15.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("172.32.0.0"), InetAddress.getByName("191.255.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("192.0.1.0"), InetAddress.getByName("192.0.1.255")));
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("192.0.3.0"), InetAddress.getByName("192.167.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("192.169.0.0"), InetAddress.getByName("198.17.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("198.20.0.0"), InetAddress.getByName("198.51.99.255")));
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("198.51.101.0"), InetAddress.getByName("203.0.112.255")));
            add(new Pair<>(InetAddress.getByName("203.0.114.0"), InetAddress.getByName("223.255.255.255")));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }};
}
```

Я не уверен, что так делать "правильно" и мне не нравится, что:

1. наполнение диапазона надо делать через `try ... catch`, хотя я знаю, что исключения там точно не возникнет;
2. Необходим диапазон именно IPv4 адресов. Если явно приводить получаемый [`InetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) к `Inet4Address`, то получится ещё бОльшая простыня кода.

Так же все конструкторы `Inet4Address` являются private, что не даёт их вызывать напрямую (в моём случае это бы решило проблему).

---

Как "правильно" решить задачу (конкретно, инстанцировать экземпляр класса, описывающего IPv4 адрес без лишних обработок исключений)? Это не обязательно должен быть `Inet4Address`, но хотелось бы, чтобы это было что-то built-in, дабы не возникали лишние зависимости.

Comment: 1) Зачем тут `getByName` если есть `getByAddress`? 2) IPv4-адрес эквивалентен четырехбайтовому целому числу, Вы уверены, что для Ваших целей этого недостаточно, без всяких `Inet4Address`?

Comment: @Yaant `getByAddress` точно так же бросает исключение. Если использовать `int` вместо адресов, то получится что-то страшное, типа `Pair<>(-2147483648, -1442971649)`, что читаемости коду не добавляет.

Comment: @Yaant К тому же, если использовать `getByAddress`, то границы диапазанов будут задаваться, как, например: `new byte[]{(byte)-87, (byte)-3, (byte)-1, (byte)-1}`, по чему совершенно не скажешь, что это `169.253.255.255`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге, пришёл к такому варианту:

```java
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Pair;

import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class IPRanges {
    static final ArrayList<Pair<Inet4Address, Inet4Address>> IPv4GlobalRanges = new ArrayList<Pair<Inet4Address, Inet4Address>>() {{
        try {
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("1.0.0.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("9.255.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("11.0.0.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("100.63.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("100.128.0.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("126.255.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("128.0.0.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("169.253.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("169.255.0.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("172.15.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("172.32.0.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("191.255.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("192.0.1.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("192.0.1.255")));
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("192.0.3.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("192.167.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("192.169.0.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("198.17.255.255")));
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("198.20.0.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("198.51.99.255")));
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("198.51.101.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("203.0.112.255")));
            add(new Pair<>((Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("203.0.114.0"), (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("223.255.255.255")));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }};
}
```

Т.е.:

- Везде сделал явное приведение к `Inet4Address`;
- В `catch` блоке заменил `e.printStackTrace();` на `throw new AssertionError(e);`, т.к. на англоязычном SO нашёл [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24863229/10941639), в котором говорится, что [`AssertionError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) следует бросать в тех местах, где исключение произойти не может.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить задавать диапазон IPv4 не с помощью класса Inet4Address, а с помощью битового представления адреса. Таким образом, для задания диапазона нам нужно либо два числа int, либо одно число типа long.

Алгоритм преобразования:
https://habr.com/ru/post/679008/